# why would the included content send to client as response body when including a no-php file using _include_

Tags: php, include

here are two files:

index.php:

```
<?php
    include 'index.txt';
?>
```

index.txt

```
Hello, Cifer.
```

when requesting index.php the browser will shows 'Hello, Cifer', what to my confusion is the mechanism of *include*, the [*PHP Manual*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) says many things about *include* but does not point out that the *include* will cause the included content to be sent to client as response body when the included content are not closed by `<?php ?>`.

so, what the mechanism of *include* in detail?

Comment: What do you think should be done when you include a text file? Trigger an error? PHP files, all PHP files, are printing out everything that is outside of `<?php ?>`. That is basic knowledge. Including the text file prints it.

Comment: @Sven I don't think it's basic, just as you say, it can trigger an error, it can just replace the line which calls _include_ with the included content, and also trigger an error when it finds that the content is not a valid php code. But it doesn't, it choose to send the content to client as response body. Yes, I know it's both reasonable and logical, but who knows if they do not write it to documentation? How do you know? By guessing? By testing? I just want an official clarification.

Comment: The official documentation you linked: "The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file." Evaluating a "PHP file" that has no opening PHP tag is simply echoed to the standard output. The file extension has no meaning - it is there to trigger the PHP parser in some web servers instead of parsing every file.

Comment: @Sven ** Evaluating a "PHP file" that has no opening PHP tag is simply echoed to the standard output. ** no this sentence, Okay, I will not bother about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you include a file, the file is ran. That's why when you `"include(header.php/footer.php)"`, it displays the header. So it's only natural that if you include a .txt file, the text will print on the page.

Answer (score 0):

When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags.
You may use HTML comment tags to avoid displaying of included file.

Comment: I don't need copy&paste answer, and the paragraph you paste is irrelevant with my question.